# Jenkins cannot build Xamarin iOS project over a missing reference to assembly netstandard

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, jenkins, msbuild

I'm trying to build a CI pipeline for a Xamarin iOS project with Jenkins, but I'm running into errors with MSBuild not finding a reference to the .NET Standard library:

```
IDebugSettingService.cs(8,22): error CS0012: The type 'IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
ViewModels/IPresentationTabViewModel.cs(17,15): error CS0012: The type 'MulticastDelegate' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
ViewModels/ICredentials.cs(17,10): error CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

I can build the project successfully on my account on the Mac build machine, but the Jenkins service account always fails here. I've tried clearing and restoring all the NuGet packages, and the MSBuild logs aren't much help, although MSBuild seems to load significantly less assemblies when run with Jenkins than when run by me.

Is this a problem with how my project is set up, or is it a problem with Jenkins?

Comment: With the same user that is running the jenkins build, are you able to build the project with your own command line?

Comment: @gunr2171 The user that runs the Jenkins build is a service account, so unfortunately I can't log in to it.

Comment: What command are you running for the build? `msbuild` or `dotnet`? Do you have the .net core runtime installed?

Comment: @gunr2171 I run `msbuild BlipBlop.sln /p:Configuration=Ad-Hoc /p:Platform=iphone /p:Buildipa=true`. The only two projects in the solution are a .NET Standard project and an iOS project. .NET core 2.1.302 is installed according to the `dotnet --version` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the `PATH` environment variable on the Jenkins account was missing the `/usr/local/share/dotnet` path and couldn't access NuGetFallbackFolder (where the NETStandard.Library reference is located) as a result.

Adding `/usr/local/share/dotnet` to `PATH` fixed the build.

Answer (score 1):

Add $Path like i have added

```
Path=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:$Path:/usr/local/share/dotnet
```

[image]

Comment: If you guys need any help in jenkins let me know. i know its hard for beginners.